# The motorcyclist's challenge

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, algebra

Three passengers $1,2,3$ starts out moving at constant speeds from $A$ to $B$. At the same time, a motorcyclist $M$ starts out from $B$ towards $A$ to pick the passengers up. As illustrated below:

[image: At the beginning]

$M$, however, can carry at most one passenger on board. He can drop his passenger off at anytime. When off the motorcycle, passengers just keep moving forward to $B$ at their respective speeds. $M$ can drive forward or backward, any way he wishes, at any speed not exceeding his top speed. Passengers will get on or off board at $M$'s bidding, and let $M$ drive them forward or backward with no complaint. We assume it takes no time to get on and off the motorcycle, or for $M$ to switch lanes to pick up different passengers.

$M$'s goal, or challenge, is to make all passengers arrive at $B$ **simultaneously**.

Now assume speeds for $1$ and $2$ are $60$ and $90$ respectively, and a top speed of $100$ for $M$.

Question: What is $3$'s speed range, if $M$ is able to accomplish his challenge?

Hint:

> Distance between $A$ and $B$ is irrelevant.

---

Here's a more involved one if you solved the above:

> Instead of 3 passengers we now have 4, where $1,2,3$ have speeds $60,90,30$ respectively. Top speed for $M$ still is $100$. What is $4$'s speed range, if $M$ is able to accomplish his challenge?

and

> In general, What relationship must the speeds for 3 passengers $s_1,s_2,s_3$ satisfy, given $s_m=100$ and $M$ is able to fulfill his challenge? What relationships must the speeds for 4 passengers satisfy?

and

> If there are many passengers and the speed of $M$ is sufficiently large relative to the speeds of passengers. What is the most efficient way (aka requiring the least amount of time) for $M$ to accomplish his challenge?

Comment: [Chvatal, "On the Bicycle Problem" (1983)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82123790.pdf)

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks. Though your reference is interesting for its own sake, I think it is a totally different problem in nature. And unlike your reference problem, my problem seems not amenable to algorithmic treatment, i.e. there exists no general algorithm that can decide whether a given speed vector $(s_1,s_2,...,s_n,s_M)$ is feasible for $M$, or if so, what schedule $M$ should make. Analysis can only be made case by case, conditioning on the number of passengers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize the problem so that the motorcycle starts at 0 with max speed 1 and the passengers start at 1.
Answer to part 1:
If passenger 3 is slower than passenger 1,

> Drive to passenger 2 and pick him up at $10/19$. (Time: $10/19$)
>  Keep driving up and drop him off at $15/19$. (Time: $15/19$)
>  Drive to $5/6$. (Time: $5/6$)
>  Drive back to 0, picking up passenger 3 whenever you meet him.
>  The first two passengers reach 0 at time $5/3$, and the third reaches 0 iff he is at $5/6$ on or before time $5/6$, which occurs if his speed it at least $1/5$.

If passenger 3 is faster than passenger 1, denote the time it takes him to walk from A to B by T.

> Drive to passenger 2 and pick him up at $10/19$. (Time: $10/19$)
>  Keep driving up and drop him off at $9T/19$. (Time: $9T/19$)
>  Drive to $T/2$. (Time: $T/2$)
>  Drive back to 0, picking up passenger 1 whenever you meet him.
>  The last two passengers reach 0 at time T, and the first reaches 0 iff he reaches $T/2$ on or before time $T/2$. Since passenger 1 has speed $3/5$, T must be at least $5/4$, forcing passenger 3's speed to be at most $4/5$.

In conclusion, passenger 3's range is

> $1/5$ to $4/5$, inclusive.

Generalizing the above approach for problem 3, let the three passengers have speeds a, b, and c, in descending order.

> The fastest passenger is picked up at 1/(1+a) and dropped off at (a/b)/(1+a).
>  We continue driving to 1/(2b). This is only possible if 1/(2b) is at least (a/b)/(1+a), which is true whenever a is at most 1.
>  We pick up the slowest passenger on the way back, and everyone arrives at time 1/b iff the slowest passenger has made it to 1/(2b) at time 1/(2b): This is true whenever c is at least 2b-1.
>  In conclusion, the fastest passenger is not faster than the motorcycle, and the middle passenger is not faster than the average of the slowest passenger and the motorcycle.

Regarding @Eric's comment, I don't believe we can do any better, and here's why:

> In order to have time to delay the middle passenger, we need to bring the fastest passenger as far back as we can.
>  This would be to some point 1/(2b) - $\epsilon$, since we have to get back to the middle passenger before he reaches 0 at time 1/b.
>  Since the farthest we move is still 1/(2b) at time 1/(2b), the slowest passenger's bounds are the same.
>  The fastest passenger will now reach 0 at time (1+1/a)/(2b), and for this to be later than 1/b (so that we can delay the middle passenger) we must still have a at most 1, and the fastest passenger's bounds are the same.

Comment: If $v_m\gt v_1\gt v_2\gt v_3$ and $2v_2=v_3+v_m+\epsilon$, what about $M$ driving **both** $v_1$ and $v_2$ backward some distance before picking up passenger $3$?

Comment: It merely makes the schedule more complicated.